# Let G=(V, E) directed graph. Let v be a vertex in G, find the number of vertices that take part in non-simple directed paths to v

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, strongly-connected-graph

Let G=(V, E) directed graph.

Let v be a vertex in G, find the number of vertices that take part in non-simple directed paths to v.

My attempt:

1. Find strongly connected components , V_1,V_2...,V_i (using DFS search produces).
2. Perform topological sorting on the V_1,V_2...,V_i.
3. Suppose v in V_j.
   Perform DFS on V_1 to V_j and count all vertex in the strongly connected
   components whose size is bigger than 1.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

First step: check your graph for cycles.  It there are none, then there are no non-simple paths..

Second: check your graph for component count.  If there is 1 component then the number of vertices that take part in non-simple directed paths is equal to the number of vertices in the graph, because every vertex can go to a vertex in a cycle, go around the cycle, and continue to the destination.

Third: Check  the component that contains v for cycles. It there are none, then there are no non-simple paths.  Otherwise  the number of vertices that take part in non-simple directed paths is equal to the number of vertices in the component.

Comment: In the third step: why check the component that contains v and not also the components which come before? (That's why I use topological sorting).

Comment: The components "that come before" are not connected to v, so their verices  cannot  take part in non-simple directed paths to v

Comment: Ohhh I talked about "strongly connected components" in my solution